# How send value from view to template form url

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am passing parameter in url i want to pass parameter from veiw by render() function and put in form url template.

### url.py

```
 path('log/<x>', csrf_exempt(views.login) , name='login-bot')
```

### veiw.py

```
def login(request, x=123):
     
     return render(request, 'chat/user_info_add.html', {'x':x} )
```

### template  (user_info_add.html)

#### here look i have put value in   **x={{x}}**  but not working mean not geting value-------

in action attribute of form i tried '{{x}}' and work just as string not that value which i was sending from veiw  but without quote it giving template syntax error:

```
<div class="first_loginbox">
   
    
    <form action="{% url 'chat:login-bot' x={{x}} %}" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class ="second_loginbox">
    <label for="login_screen" class="label_login">Add Info</label><br>
    <input  type="email" class="form-control marg"  " name="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address">
    <input id="css2" type="text" class="form-control marg " name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
    <button id = "css3" class="btn btn-outline-success">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Please if any one could help **how we put value inside**   {% url 'chat:login-bot' **{{x}}** %}.

## error

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '{{x}}' from '{{x}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the url tag, or any other built-in template tag and filter for that matter, you don't need to declare the 'django variable' with extra `{{ }}`.
You just have to use the default `x`. the way you declare it in your context, so it should be:

```py
action="{% url 'chat:login-bot' x %}"
```

> **Note:** Always add `/` at the end of every route, so:

```
path('log/<x>/', csrf_exempt(views.login), name='login-bot')
```

If nothing is specified in url params, so by default that is considered string type.

For e.g. `"log/<x>/"` and `"log/<str:x>/"` is same.